# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I execute my project, I get this error:
[image]

The goal is to save `json` text into a database using **hibernate**.

`Users.java` & `UsersBooks.java` is likewise,

[image]

**Books.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tblbooks")
public class Books {


@Id
@Column(name = "bookshareId")
private int bookshareId;

@Column(name="author")
private String author;

@Column(name = "availableToDownload")
private int availableToDownload;

@Column(name = "briefSynopsis")
private String briefSynopsis;

@Column(name="category")
private String category;

@Column(name = "completeSynopsis")
private String completeSynopsis;

@Column(name = "contentId")
private int contentId;

@Column(name = "copyright")
private Date copyright;

@Column(name="downloadFormat")
private String downloadFormat;

@Column(name="dtbookSize")
private int dtbookSize;

@Column(name = "freelyAvailable")
private int freelyAvailable;

@Column(name = "brf")
private int brf;

@Column(name = "daisy")
private int daisy;

@Column(name = "images")
private int images;

@Column(name = "isbn13")
private String isbn13;

@Column(name="language")
private String language;

@Column(name = "publishDate")
private Date publishDate;

@Column(name = "publisher")
private String publisher;

@Column(name = "quality")
private String quality;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="book")
private List<UsersBooks> usersBooks;



//Getters & Setters
```

Comment: into database you have been settle field type character and it's length is 255, which is cause here, please, either max. 255 to 1000 (longer then 255) or change type from character to text or varchar.

Comment: What is the SQL sent to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You try to save a string value more than 255 chars length. Just increase a column length

```
@Column(name = "xxx", length = 1024)
```

you need to alter a column length in the database too.

When you use

```
@Column(name = "xxx")
```

Hibernate uses a default column length.

You can use `@Lob` for a really large text data.

Please, use `xxx_users` in place of `tblusers`.

Use `User` in place of `Users`.

Use `CascadeType.ALL` on the `@OneToMany` part of the association.

Use a lazy loading on the `@ManyToOne` part of the association.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
pravate User user;
```

Answer (score 16):

For String with more than 255 chars length you can increase column length :

```
@Column(length = 2048)
private String column;
```

For large size :

```
@Lob
private String column;
```

For unlimited size :

```
@Column(columnDefinition="text")
private String column;
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells that you are trying to store a String which is too large for its destination column (255).

You can either :

- Increase the column size or
- Change the column type to `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR(255)`.